# How to make all the turtles move simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

I want to move all the turtles at the same time, and I want to be able to create 100 turtles. I have to create each one separately in the code so creating 100's of them, or more, will take a long time. I want a way to be able to set the number of turtles I want -- a number from 100 and up. And I want them to move all the same time. I would like to set boundary for as well. Any ideas on how to do any of this or all of it will be appreciated.

To conclude, I want to be able to:

- Set the number of turtle generated.
- Move all of it at once not one
  each time.
- Set boundary so it can't go anywhere.

Note: I also know there are a couple questions that were asked but no efficient answer was provided.  My code:

```
import turtle
import numpy as np

tlist = list()
colorlist = ["red", "green", "black", "blue", "brown"]
for i in range(5):
    tlist.append(turtle.Turtle(shape="turtle"))
    tlist[i].color(colorlist[i])
    tlist[i].speed(1)
screen = turtle.getscreen()
for i in range(30):

    for t in tlist:
        t.speed(1)
        t.right((np.random.rand(1) - .5) * 180)
        t.forward(int((np.random.rand(1) - .5) * 100))
    screen.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need "one smart person in here" to solve this, you need to spend more of your own time searching the wealth of turtle examples on SO.  However, I will take this on as a personal challenge to write minimalist code to put 100 turtles into bounded random motion:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 600, 600
CURSOR_SIZE, TURTLE_SIZE = 20, 10
TURTLES = 100

def move():
    for turtle in screen.turtles():
        turtle.forward(1)
        x, y = turtle.position()

        if not (TURTLE_SIZE - WIDTH/2 < x < WIDTH/2 - TURTLE_SIZE and TURTLE_SIZE - HEIGHT/2 < y < HEIGHT/2 - TURTLE_SIZE):
            turtle.undo()  # undo forward()
            turtle.setheading(randint(1, 360))  # change heading for next iteration

    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(move)

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

for turtle in range(TURTLES):
    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.shapesize(TURTLE_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
    turtle.shape('turtle')
    turtle.setheading(randint(1, 360))
    turtle.goto(randint(TURTLE_SIZE - WIDTH/2, WIDTH/2 - TURTLE_SIZE), randint(TURTLE_SIZE - HEIGHT/2, HEIGHT/2 - TURTLE_SIZE))

move()

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Comment: saying "smart person" was just being nice I know this does not require much, but it's good to be nice and yes I m trying to learn and search for answers this is part of it that help me learn and save me a lot of time in my learning process.